# growl framework osx and sandboxing

Tags: xcode, macos, growl, sandbox

I was going to build a new project based on an old one. So when i tried to run the old one i got this message from XCode:

[image: XCode Message]

But the application started normally and the growl notification worked as expected:
[image: growl notification]

The old project(sandboxed) succeeded the app store review and is in selling status since Oct 23, 2012.
Do you think there is something wrong here or i should just ignore the XCode message and use the old code on my new project? Also did someone else had the same issue and how did you manage it?
I use osx 10.7 and XCode 4.5.2